# Elasticsearch is setting a 1.0 score to all results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following json in Kibana's console:

```
GET /sgn-audit/_search

{
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10",
  "sort": [
    {
      "updated_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "owner_type": "taskStatus"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "owner_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "tenant_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "updated_at": {
                "gte": "2021-02-11T00:00:00Z",
                "lte": "2021-02-11T23:59:59Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However all results are returning with a 1.0 score and even results that don't match the queries above return as well, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bewildered me a few times too! Simply remove the whitespace between the URI and the search body:

```
GET /sgn-audit/_search
    <---
{
 ...
```

Comment: Man, are you serious? Why isn't that an error in kibana?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Yup  It doesn't recognize it as an error -- it's just not applying *any* request body.